# how to make cloudant pick a .pac file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cloudant, pac, python-cloudant

In my python (2.7) application I make use of a Cloudant database as follows:

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant

client = Cloudant('XXX', 'YYY', account='ZZZ')
client.connect()
my_db = client['my_database']
for doc in my_db: print doc
```

The environment in which this application runs makes use of proxy.pac which can not be bypassed. How could I make the connection to Cloudant .pac aware or how could I let Cloudant automatically look for proxy.pac?

I've found the python package PyPac (https://pypac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but do not have the slightest idea how I should use this in the Cloudant context.

Thanks for your ideas and help in advance.

Comment: The comment I received from direct email: "python-cloudant does not support PAC files. The only proxy support in python-cloudant at the moment is that provided by the underlying requests library. We don't expose a way to customize the arguments on every request, but you should be able to configure a proxy address to be used via the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable, but this isn't something we've tested AFAIK."

Comment: Where is located the file "proxy.pac"?

Comment: Are you kidding? Can be anywhere.

Comment: OK, let's retry: do you know the exact location of the file in your environment? I am asking because you will need to kknow that before trying to use pypac.

Comment: In some cases you will know the location in others not. So PyPac provides automated pac finder functionality. So for this case let's assume we know the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PyPAC 0.6.0, you can use the `pac_context_for_url` context manager:

```
from pypac import pac_context_for_url


with pac_context_for_url('https://acct.cloudant.com'):
    # Do your Cloudant stuff
```

---

Original answer:

This should work as expected:

```
import os

import pypac


# PyPAC will auto-discover the current PAC settings
pac = pypac.get_pac()

# Find the proxy for Cloudant (I use this domain but anything else would work too)
proxies = pac.find_proxy_for_url('https://acct.cloudant.com', 'cloudant.com')

# It will return something like: 'PROXY 4.5.6.7:8080; PROXY 7.8.9.10:8080'
# Here we take the 1st one:
proxy = 'http://{}/'.format(proxies.split()[1].rstrip(';'))

# Set proxy envars
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy

# And now try Cloudant stuff
```

Comment: Hmmm, sometimes life can be so easy! :) Looks good to me. Never came up this simple but effective solution. Thanks very much.